# SlimFramework enviar json para url de outra aplicação

Tags: slim

Estou desenvolvendo um integração de sistemas, e estou usando o Slim frameWork estou usando um Action chamada Cron <- foi criada por min.

Na Cron tem um method chamado verificarComplited

```
private function verificarComplited($id, $status = 0){

    try
    {
        $complited = $this->db->prepare("select * from completed where id = :id");
        $complited->bindParam("id", $id);
        $complited->execute();
        if ($complited->rowCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        }else{
            $moduloCompleted = $complited->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $json = json_encode($moduloCompleted);
            $app->post('http://localhost:8888/', function ($json) use ($app){

            });

        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "erro ao adicionar usuario tabela mdl_user_enrolments";
        return "erro ao adicionar usuario tabela mdl_user_enrolments";

    }


}
```

Eu preciso enviar o $json para um url fora do meu projeto como eu posso fazer isso ?

Comment: `$app->post` é o que?

Comment: ele não esta funcionando, teria como vc me dar uma dica ?

Comment: o contexto para solução é maior então precisa colocar na sua pergunta todo ele, para tentar ajudar! só com esse trecho fica complicado.

Comment: ok, vou tentar deixar mais claro.